# How to deref tuple of references

Tags: rust

```
use std::collections::BTreeMap;

fn main() {
    let mut m = BTreeMap::new();
    m.insert(1, 1);
    
    let (a, b) = *m.iter().next().unwrap();
}
```

I am trying to get de-refed version of (key, value) pair returned from the btreemap. But using dereference operator directly upon the returned (& ,&) pair is not working.

Is there a way to do this so that the type of a, b are just u64, not &u64?

Comment: You could always shadow the variables with a derefed version, e.g. `let (a, b) = (*a, *b);`, though I'm not sure how you could do it in one statement

Comment: Or you could iterate by value using `into_iter` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `&` before a variable in a *pattern* (used by `let`) will dereference it.

```
let (&a, &b) = m.iter().next().unwrap();
```